# Existing home. Lived here for years. Breaker popped loud sound, help!

Tags: electrical

Heard a loud pop, and the ac breaker popped. Ac man came out and said it's something with my box. Every time he flipped the breaker back on it would spark by the grounds and the breaker would pop back off. The screw that held the strip, all the grounds on that side run into, was loose and stripped. So I replaced the screw and it's solid now. Put everything back together and as soon as I  turned that breaker on, it sparks by the ground and behind the breaker its self. I can't afford a electrician after the ac man's bill. My kids are miserable with no air and truthfully, we all are. Can anyone give me an idea of what is wrong. We have live here years with no problem. Help!

Comment: What the heck sort of crusty old breaker box do you have?  Can you post a photo of that sparky bastard for us?

Answer (score 7):

This is a serious electrical risk. You (and your kids) cannot afford **NOT** to have an electrician come and check out this dangerous situation. Attempting to bypass the problem without expert advice risks **fire** and **electrocution**.

Answer (score 3):

> Every time he flipped the breaker back on it would spark by the grounds

Sparks anywhere in an electrical system are generally bad.

> ...and the breaker would pop back off

Good. It's supposed to do that. You should stop flipping it on.

> The screw that held the strip, all the grounds on that side run into, was loose and stripped

Also bad. Electrical connections like to be snug and secure. Otherwise they spark.

> So I replaced the screw and it's solid now

How, exactly, did you do this? You went to a home center and got exactly the right size and length of screw for this breaker panel? If you used something from the "assorted parts" drawer you probably have a near-short circuit in your panel. The "sparks behind the breaker" say this is likely.

> We have live here years with no problem

Means nothing. Corrosion and compression take years to create problems.

Based on what you have described you have a serious electrical problem. If you are renting, call the landlord. If you own, call an electrician. Do that today. Whatever the electrician charges will be far less than the cost of the house fire and/or funerals that result from bad electrical systems.